# Ambiguous step definitions

Tags: .net, regex, specflow

I am having following two step definitions:

```
[When(@"I Schedule a Start Now Event named ""(.*)"" for the DR program named ""(.*)""")]

[When(@"I Schedule a Start Now Event named ""(.*)"" for the DR program named ""(.*)"" with load control device ""(.*)""")]
```

When using the above two step definitions in scenario, I could see the second step definition is not able to bind.

This is because, when I commented out the second step definition, my step bids to the first step definition as follows:

```
When I Schedule a Start Now Event named "~@+Event" for the DR program named "~@=Program" with load control device "Light"
```

The term `"~@=Program" with load control device "Light"` is assumed as single string value. But it should not supposed to be.

It should bind with the second step definition.

Is this a Regex pattern issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you need to be more specific:

```
[When(@"I Schedule a Start Now Event named ""([^""]*)"" for the DR program named ""([^""]*)""")]

[When(@"I Schedule a Start Now Event named ""([^""]*)"" for the DR program named ""([^""]*)"" with load control device ""([^""]*)""")]
```

Making the `*` reluctant would probably do just as well:

```
[When(@"I Schedule a Start Now Event named ""(.*?)"" for the DR program named ""(.*?)""")]

[When(@"I Schedule a Start Now Event named ""(.*?)"" for the DR program named ""(.*?)"" with load control device ""(.*?)""")]
```

...but the negated character class is more foolproof.  Disclaimer: I'm not a SpecFlow user myself, but [this blog post](http://shades-of-orange.com/post/2013/05/13/SpecFlow-Step-Definition-with-Optional-Parameter) seems to confirm my guess.

Answer (score 1):

Its a regex pattern issue, but also a fairly common problem.

Basically the regex `.*` is known as greedy. It will match everything it can from where it appears until something forces it not to match. Alan Moore's suggestion of using quotes will work quite nicely. Another is to use names that don't contain spaces, then you can use `[^ ]*` meaning match many not spaces.

I would actually suggest that you might find it easier to build up your queries with smaller statements. For example

```
Given a DR program called xxx
And a load control device xxx
When I schedule a Start now event named xxx

private string drProgramName;
private string loadControlDevice;

[Given("a DR program called (.*)"]
public void GivenADRProgramCalled(string name)
{
  drProgamName = name;
}

[Given("a load control device (.*)"]
public void GivenALoadControlDevice(string name)
{
  loadControlDevice = name;
}

[When("I schedule a start now event named (.*)")]
public void WhenIScheduleAStartNowEventNamed(string name)
{
  WhenIScheduleAStartNowEventNamed(name, drProgamName, loadControlDevice);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [Blog](http://shades-of-orange.com/post/2013/05/13/SpecFlow-Step-Definition-with-Optional-Parameter) post really solved my issue. Cheers Alan!!